# Как узнать общее время работы потока после его зарождения?

Tags: c#

В программе несколько потоков выполняют одну и ту же функцию. Как узнать общее время выполнения потоков после их зарождения, т.е. после начала команды Start()?

Comment: Что такое "время зарождения потока"?

Comment: @АндрейNOP исправил вопрос, так правильней

Comment: Ну так запоминайте время когда вы вызываете Start() или запускайте Stopwatch.

Comment: Вам нужна сумма по всем потокам? Если да, то надо будет через lock записывать суммарное время во внешнюю для потоков переменную.

Comment: Процессорное время или время выполнения? Это, в общем случае, разные вещи.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight время работы потока после его зарождения

Answer (score 1):

при старте потока:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
```

в конце потока:

```
stopWatch.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds));
```